# Probability of at least some number of heads

Tags: probability

Let's say you flip a fair coin 50 times. What is the probability that you get at least 15 heads?

Any hints?

Comment: possible outcomes would be 50 choose 15 + 50 choose 16 + ... 50 choose 50?

Comment: Correct, and the probability is $\frac{281108753635567}{281474976710656}\approx 0.998698914$

Answer (score 1):

For each flip of the coin, there are $2$ possible outcomes, heads $(H)$ or tails $(T)$. Probability of each event is $0.5$. So we use the notation $\text{Pr}(H) = \text{Pr}(T)=0.5$.

What you are actually looking for is the **Binomial Distribution**, which tells you the probability of getting $x$ number of heads out of $50$. To calculate that, I'd recommend using some software to do it. If $X$ is the number of heads, you would need to calculate $\text{Pr}(X=0) = \binom {50} 0(0.5)^0(0.5)^{50}$, then repeat for $x=1, 2, \cdots$ until $14$. Subtract this total from $1$ and you get your answer.

Comment: Um, surely you mean $\binom{50}{0}$?

Comment: changed, thanks for your good eye @anorton. I have not done this in a long time already

Answer (score 1):

Another way, you can apply the Central Limit Theorem: use $\mathbf{E}X = 50 \cdot \frac{1}{2}$ and $sd_{X} = \sqrt{\mathbf{Var}X} = \sqrt{50 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}} = \frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}$. Now use this information to find the probability 
$$
P\bigg(\frac{X - \mathbf{E}X}{sd_X}>\frac{15-25}{\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}}\bigg) = P(Z>-2 \sqrt{2})
$$
where $Z \sim N(0,1)$.